# Integrate this expression involving exponential and polynomial $\int_0^\infty\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{(\lambda + b)^2}\, \text{d}\lambda$

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I tried a few ways (integral by parts, expanding), but I'm unable to compute this integral.

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{(\lambda + b)^2}\, \text{d}\lambda$$

$n \geq 0, b \geq 0$

Comment: Whether it is helpful or not, I see the $\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}$ and think Gamma function.

Comment: What are $b$, $n$?

Comment: Basically I am trying to find the marginal likelihood of poisson (rate parameter) with the prior $(\lambda +b)^{-2}$. n is the number of events observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is a non-negative integer you can put $\mu = \lambda + b $ so that the integral becomes 
$$ e^b \int_b^{\infty} \frac{(\mu-b)^n e^{-\mu}}{\mu^2} d\mu = e^b \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-b)^{n-k} \int_b^{\infty} \mu^{k-2} e^{-\mu} d\mu$$ Then, except for when $k=0$ or $1$, the integrals in the sum can be solved using integration by parts whereas
$$ \int_b^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\mu}}{\mu}d\mu = -\text{Ei}(-b) \,\,\,,\,\,\, \int_b^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\mu}}{\mu^2}d\mu = \text{Ei}(-b) + \frac{e^{-b}}{b}$$

Comment: The integrals in the sum represent the [Incomplete Gamma functon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), namely $$\int_b^{\infty} \mu^{k-2} e^{-\mu} ~d \mu=\Gamma(k-1,b)$$

Answer (score 3):

Even for $n=0$, the integral requires special functions, see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[[Lambda]%5E0*Exp[-[Lambda]]%2F%28[Lambda]+%2B+b%29%5E2,+[Lambda]]), so there probably is no simple way of computing it.

For $n=0$, the result is
$$-e^b \text{Ei}(-b-\lambda )-\frac{e^{-\lambda }}{b+\lambda }$$